# why these integrals fail to evaluate in V 13 compared to V 12.3?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-13

This was also reported to WRI. **[CASE:4903465]**

I'd like to know why these integrals no longer evaluate in V 13 and timeout after 3 minutes while using the same PC and OS they all evaluate quickly in time using V 12.3.

Is there is a workaround in V 13?

This is on windows 10.  64 GB RAM.  These integrals come from Rubi's input test files.

The timeout is there to prevent the script from hanging forever.

Is this a bug in integrate?

I also include at bottom a link to the notebook in V 13 and V 12.3 with the code and output to download.

```
Clear["Global`*]
timeOut = 3*60;
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Cot[e + f*x]^2*(a + a*Sin[e + f*x])^(1/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Cot[e + f*x]^4*(a + a*Sin[e + f*x])^(1/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Csc[c + d*x]^2*(a + a*Sin[c + d*x])^(2/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Csc[c + d*x]*(a + a*Sin[c + d*x])^(4/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Csc[c + d*x]^2*(a + a*Sin[c + d*x])^(4/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Csc[c + d*x]^2/(a + a*Sin[c + d*x])^(1/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Csc[c + d*x]^2/(a + a*Sin[c + d*x])^(4/3), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[(d*Sin[e + f*x])^(5/2)/((g*Cos[e + f*x])^(3/2)*(a + b*Sin[e + f*x])), x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[1/((d*Sec[e + f*x])^(5/3)*(a + b*Tan[e + f*x])),x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[1/((d*Sec[e + f*x])^(1/3)*(a + b*Tan[e + f*x])^2),x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[Tan[c + d*x]^(2/3)/Sqrt[a + b*Tan[c + d*x]], x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[1/(Tan[c + d*x]^(4/3)*Sqrt[a + b*Tan[c + d*x]]),x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[(a + a*Sec[c + d*x])^2/Sqrt[e*Sin[c + d*x]], x], timeOut]
TimeConstrained[Integrate[(a + a*Sec[c + d*x])^n*Tan[c + d*x]^(3/2), x], timeOut]
```

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Link to the notebooks is [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/reports/summer_2022/mathematica_regression/report.htm)

Comment: Whenever you use assumptions, Mathematica V13 computes these integrals.

Comment: What answer are you expecting here that you would not get from Technical Services? I'm thinking this falls into the category of "The question is out of scope for this site. The answer to this question requires either advice from Wolfram support..."

Comment: @E.Chan-López That observation should be made into an answer as that does provide a fix.

Comment: Reminds me of this, where you posted that MMA lost the ability to compute a set of integrals in going from 11.2 to 11.3.  As you know, that was subsequently fixed in 12.0: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169209/some-indefinite-integrals-evaluate-in-11-2-but-not-in-11-3-what-can-be-done  I gather that you typically evaluate new releases with Rubi's test suite, to see if there are issues, which is useful. Given that Wolfram is aware of what happened with 11.3, I would think that, by now, Wolfram should know to include this suite as part of their own Q&A SOP's.

Answer (score 7):

I was trying different settings, I found a solution to this problem.

Now they **all** evaluate in V 13 as they did in  V 12.3.

You need to add this setting at the top (this is new in V 13.0)

```
SetSystemOptions["IntegrateOptions" -> "UseIntegrateAlgebraic" -> False];
```

The default was `True`

As an example of one of the above

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

`IntegrateAlgebraic` is very good in solving many integrals that could not be solved easily before and it does it fast, but it looks like there is a small clitch somewhere integrating `IntegrateAlgebraic` into V 13 `Integrate` command.

I also noticed I needed to start with Clean kernel when changing the this setting from `True` to `False` or vis verse for the new settings to take effect. Not sure why.

The V13 notebook showing they all now evaluate can be downloaded from [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/reports/summer_2022/mathematica_regression/V_13_fixed.nb).

Comment: Well, open the bug. IntegrateAlgebraic is open source. I also found that it cannot solve any Chebyshev-Zolotarev integrals either like this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784897/how-to-apply-rischs-algorithm-to-int-fracx-sqrtx4-2x33x24x1-mat Fricas does it, no problem.

Comment: https://github.com/stblake/algebraic_integration

Comment: I found it that a) it can do my example above it if we increase time allowed for IntegrateAlgebraic to 20 seconds b) your issue is a bug, because it is supposed to turn off IntegrateAlgebraic after 10 seconds. SetSystemOptions[
      "IntegrateOptions" -> {"IntegrateAlgebraicTimeConstraint" -> 20}];

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use assumptions, Mathematica V13 computes these integrals.

For example:

[image]

I think it's convenient to use assumptions, since the integral has several parameters that could be interpreted as complex by Mathematica.

Comment: Note that the `\[Element] Reals` at the end of your assumptions is (I think) unnecessary; telling Mathematica that `{a > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0}` automatically includes the assumptions that they're real-valued.

Comment: @Michael Seifert You're right, I appreciate the comment.